# How to fetch only WhatsApp Contacts from iPhone Contacts?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, contacts, whatsapp

How can I fetch only WhatsApp contacts from iPhone contact list using swift.

I fetched contacts information from my phone got following response:

**whats app contact**

```
    <CNContact: 0x13bd92310: identifier=04B80557-011F-4437-B132-43E2B0D70CD9, givenName=Tech, familyName=.vijaykart, organizationName=, phoneNumbers=("<CNLabeledValue: 0x170661e80: identifier=579A8A18-F113-4C6E-878A-68D18BFE4A8B, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x17023f420: countryCode=in, digits=+919791291980>>"), emailAddresses=(not fetched), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>
```

**Non WhatsApp contact**

```
    <CNContact: 0x13bd808d0: identifier=E09E916A-7829-4288-8731-A3789FA75F18, givenName=Kcm, familyName=Milk, organizationName=, phoneNumbers=("<CNLabeledValue: 0x174264bc0: identifier=CCF42FEB-2062-4425-81B9-1BF9EABE771C, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x17422ddc0: countryCode=in, digits=+919443551702>>"),emailAddresses=(not fetched), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>
```

But not able to detect if it's WhatsApp contact or not.

Comment: i think it is not possible.Because apple not allowed to access other apps Data.So you can get the contact list but not WhatsApp contacts.

Comment: But apple is displaying "Found in WhatsApp" tag in contact. How they are detecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes according to @Bittoo who have commented above is rit, It is not possible to get only WhatsApp contact, IOS Not allowed you to get others data within the app without the apps permission, if suppose WhatsApp provides their sdk like FB or instagram then it may allowed you through their sdk, if user phone has whatsapp installed, then through their sdk, they may allow you to get their contacts.

Comment: Same question with @Suman: But apple is displaying "Found in WhatsApp" tag in contact. How they are detecting?